# Rails Simple_form - How can I wrap error_notification in a div

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I'm using the simple_form gem in Rails to create a form. To handle the server side errors I'm using:

```
<%= f.error_notification %>
```

And when the form is submitted and server-side errors are generated, they're generated in a p tag like so:

```
<p class="error_notification">Here are all the errors....</p>
```

I want wrap a **div** around the **p** element, because I'd like to create a red background for the message container via CSS, and I don't want to style the **P** element directly. Is there some way to do this inside of Rails with simple_form?

Comment: Do you mind the `div`-element being empty when there is no error? If not, just put `<div>` and `</div>` around the `error_notification` :)

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was trying to avoid :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen this here: https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/blob/master/lib/generators/simple_form/templates/config/initializers/simple_form.rb, line 65

```
# Default tag used for error notification helper.
  config.error_notification_tag = :div
```

Comment: This is a good start, but what I want to do is wrap the div around the tag, not just change the tag itself.

Comment: Maybe you could surroung it with a div (css property: display:inline;) and make your p display:block; (with this your div should be invisible if there is nothing in the p tag)

Comment: Yeah, what I'm trying to avoid is having the empty div (see comments in the original). Maybe there's no avoiding it, in which case your answer is a pretty good solution.

Comment: You would need to use Javascript in this case. Something that "detect" the <p> tag and surroung it with a div, like this: `$('p.error_notification').wrap("<div class='error' />");`